# What is the minimum generating set of a matrix group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Any finite group $G$ can be generated $G=\langle A\rangle$ by a finite set $A$. A minimal generating set for $G$ is a generating set $A$ of minimal size.
For example, any cyclic group has a minimal generating set of size 1; and a minimal generating set for the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is $\{r,s\}$.

What would be the minimal generating set for the group $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: For this particular group we have $GL(3, 3) \cong PSL(3, 3) \times \Bbb Z_2$, but $PSL(3, 3)$ is simple and noncyclic and so requires exactly $2$ generators. Thus, the size of the minimal generating set is $2$ or $3$.

Comment: @Travis  Could you please explain how you concluded the size of the required set to be 2 or 3? Also, since we need the minimal set, how can it be of two different sizes?

Comment: Like I wrote, $PSL(3, 3)$ can be generated by two elements $s, t$ but not one. Also, $\Bbb Z_2$ is generated by the nonidentity element $u$, so $\{(s, 0), (t, 0), (0, u)\}$ is a generating set for $\Bbb Z_2$, but this does not preclude the possibility that $GL(3, 3)$ could be generated by two elements. The minimal set cannot "be of two different sizes": My comment only gives lower and upper bounds for the size of such a set.

Comment: @Travis I think this is an extreme case of using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, particularly since the nut seems to end up uncracked at the end of the process.  The result that all finite simple groups are $2$-generated requires the classification of finite simple groups, and is not easy even then. It is also a known result that the groups ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ are $2$-generated for all prime powers $q$, so why not use that one? I would guess that this problem is intended to be solved directly.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh yes, I agree---as you probably know, the result is equivalent to the classification in the sense that the classification would be much easier if one knew a priori that all finite simple groups are $2$-generated---and this (together with the lack of cracking) is why I posted my remark as a comment. In any case, I was unaware of the result of the $2$-generation of all groups $GL(n, q)$---thanks for alerting me to this!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know how to answer this question most helpfully without knowing more about your background, and where this problem comes from.

In fact ${\rm GL}(3,3)$ is generated by the two matrices
$$ a = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{array}\right),\ \ \ \ \ \
b = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{array}\right).$$
Note first that $a \not\in {\rm SL}(3,3)$, so it is enough to prove that ${\rm SL}(3,3) = \langle a^2,b\rangle$ and that $ a^2 = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)$ is a so-called transvection. Now $b$ is a permutation matrix, and it is easily seen that
$$b^{-1}a^2b= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),\ \ \ 
[a^2,b^{-1}a^2b]= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),\ \ \ b^{-1}[a^2,b^{-1}a^2b]b= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),$$
and by further conjugations by $b$ we get all of the upper and lower unitriangular matrices that represent transvections.

Showing that ${\rm SL}(3,3)$ is generated by these transvection matrices is just basic linear algebra, and is essntially equivalent to row and column reducing an invertible matrix. (You can make life easier by using the diagonal matrix $a^3$ and conjugates under $b$ to handle diagonal entries equal to $-1$.)